# How to create Zip in Yii2

Tags: php, zip, yii2

I have tried to create zip file using PHP ZipArchive in Yii2. But it show me error in my code .. I couldn't found my error ...

```
public actionZip(){
          $zip = new ZipArchive();
          print_r($zip);
          exit;
          $zip->close();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Stack overflow but i found the answer of this question

```
public actionZip(){
                  $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                  print_r($zip);
                  exit;
                  $zip->close();
                   }
```